# PySpark: cast nullType field as string under struct type column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a dataframe which has the following schema. The `translation_version` field under `translations --> languages (no, pt,...)` column is in `null`. I want to cast all `translation_version` as string. I have 17 languages under `translations`

```
root
|-- translations: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- no: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- Description: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- class: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- translation_version: null (nullable = true) // Want to cast as string
|    |-- pt: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- Description: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- class: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- translation_version: null (nullable = true)
|    |-- fr: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- Description: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- class: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- translation_version: null (nullable = true)
```

I tried `df = df.na.fill('null')` but didn't change anything. Also tried to cast with the following code

```
df = df.withColumn("translations", F.col("translations").cast("struct<struct<translation_version: string>>"))
```

but this returned the following error

```
pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: u"\nmismatched input '<' expecting ':'(line 1, pos 13)\n\n== SQL ==\nstruct<struct<translation_version: string>>\n-------------^^^\n"
```

Any idea how to cast all `translation_version` as string for each language?

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, struct
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

schema_ = StructType([StructField("Description",StringType(),True),
                      StructField("class",StringType(),True),
                      StructField("description",StringType(),True),
                      StructField("translation_version",StringType(),True)
                     ]
                    )

df_1 = (
    df
    .select("translations.*")
    .withColumn("translations", struct(
        col("fr").cast(schema).alias("fr"),
        col("pt").cast(schema).alias("pt"),
        col("no").cast(schema).alias("no")
               )
               )
    .drop("fr", "pt", "no")
)
```